# php stream two files as binary to show download prompt

Tags: php, file, download, http-headers

I have a download.php file with this source:

```php
<?php
$filename = $_GET['file'];
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");
readfile($filename);
?>
```

This is just for demonstration sake. It can stream a file and show a download prompt. But this only works with one file. What if I want to stream two or three files? Is there any more elegant solution than to keep redirecting the page two or three times until all files are downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an html page with multiple iframes, each iframe pointing to a download url.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to stream multiple files, not cross-browser in any case.

You could stream a zip-file with multiple files though.